# angular2 lazy loading routes forchild navigate relativeTo

Tags: angular, routes, loading, lazy-evaluation

I'm lazy loading a module in witch I define its own routes.

I missing the 'root' path of the module (module-root-path in the code) in
router.navigate( PATH, {relativeTo: this._activatedRoute}).

What am I missing ?

The code (omitting imports and co for clarity):

```
// app-routing.module.ts
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'module-root-path',
    loadChildren: './child/child.module#ChildModule',
  },
  ...,
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
  ],
  exports: [ RouterModule, ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }




//ChildModule
const moduleRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '',
    component: moduleComponent1,
    canActivateChild: [ ModuleGuard, ],
    children: [
      { path: '',
        component: moduleComponent2,
      },
    ]
  },
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
  ],
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(moduleRoutes),
  ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class ChildRoutingModule {}

// ***** The code of the guard ****
// ModuleGuard
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { CanActivate, CanActivateChild, CanLoad,
         ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot,
         Route, Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class ModuleGuard implements CanActivateChild {
  constructor(
    private _router: Router,
    private _activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute
  ) {}

  canActivateChild(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    routerState: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): boolean {
    if (SOMETHING_NOT_TRUE) { return true; }

    // This does not work as I'm getting path
    //    /path_relative and not /module-root-path/path_relative
    this._router.navigate(
      ['path_relative'],
      { relativeTo: this._activatedRoute,
        queryParams: { returnUrl: routerState.url }
      }
    );

    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain a little bit better what is your problem exactly?

Comment: Hello,  I was hoping that the relativeTo in navigate would include the 'prefix' of the module and would result (in this example) into the path /module-root-path/path_relative.  It doesn't as this navigate return the absolute path /path_relative.  It is loosing the module's prefix-path and therefor doesn't navigate correctly

Comment: In which component are you using router.navigate() with the relativeTo argument? Could you post the relevant part of the .ts file?

Comment: In the ModuleGuard (last part of the code)

Comment: can you please add the guard ts code?

Comment: I marked it with ***** The code of the guard ****.

Comment: Thanks Ill take a look, at first glance it seems that using an instance of ActivatedRouteSnapshot for the relativeTo option in the navigate method isnt really supported. The type of relativeTo should be ActivatedRoute. Ill take a closer look